# Can't delete file in java on windows ....?

Tags: java

I am trying to use `file.delete()` but it does not delete file ? I tested it on `linux` it delete files but on `windows` it does not delete file why..?

code :

```
private File getFiletobeUpload(File foto) {

    boolean errorRename = true;
    File uploadFile = null;
    File testFile = foto;
    String subdirname = this.checkDir(foto);

    if (testFile.canWrite()) {
        uploadFile = new File(AppConstants.PHOTOPATH + "/" + subdirname +  "/" + testFile.getName());


        try {
            FileInputStream origStream = new FileInputStream(testFile);
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(uploadFile);
            origStream.getChannel().transferTo(0, testFile.length(), outStream.getChannel());
            origStream.close();
            origStream = null;
            outStream.close();
            outStream = null;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.errorString += "error while writing to orig dir";
            logger.error(e);
        }

        errorRename = !testFile.delete();
        if (errorRename) {
            this.errorString += "error while deleting the file";
        }
    }

    testFile = null;
    return uploadFile;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you don't have file permission. Either set directory to allow the Java Program, or run the java program with an elevated permission.

Comment: I think it may be some security reasons.You don't have permission to which you want to delete.

Comment: no if i delete manually on window then it deletes.....

Comment: Are you running the code as `administrator` rights?

Comment: yes running the code as administrator

Comment: @DeveloperDesk did you right click eclipse/ide/commandprompt and click `run as administrator`?

Comment: I am using netbeans IDE

Comment: Is the `uploadFile` created?

Comment: @DeveloperDesk right click netbeans and select `run as administrator`

Answer (score 0):

your code seems a bit odd, you are checking "testFile" for write access but then actually reading from it (FileInputStream). Is the first try/catch block running without exception? Maybe you should check if the file even exists:

```
System.out.println("File exists: "+testFile.exists());
errorRename = !testFile.delete();
```

Also if you just want to rename a file, use:

```
 file.renameTo(File dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

A general suggestion: consider using the classes in the [java.nio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package to your file IO if you can (not sure which version of Java you're running with) because the error handling is improved and you should be able to find a more specific reason for the failure based on the type of exception thrown and the exception message.

Answer (score -1):

As per [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), the disk-drive specifier - "/" for the UNIX root directory, and "\\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname.

so for windows:

```
uploadFile = new File(AppConstants.PHOTOPATH + "\\" + subdirname +  "\\" + testFile.getName());
```